# AngularJS ng-view not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I followed this guide: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

But when I try to change the view nothing happens, anybody a idea what I do wrong?

This is the code I got.
Home.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="lax">
<head>
    <meta name="author" content="Koen Desmedt" />
    <meta name="description" content="CMS Belgium Lacrosse" />
    <meta name="keywords" content='Lacrosse, BLF, Belgium' />
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive" />
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lax.js"></script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">        
    <title>CMS Belgium Lacrosse</title>
</head>
<body>        
    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>                    
            </div>
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/home">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> BLF
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/players">Players</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/club">Club</a>                            
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/games">Games</a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>             
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id='contentcontainer'>
        <div class='container' ng-view></div>
    </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

lax.js:

```
var lax = angular.module('lax', []);

lax.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
            when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'views/news.php',
                controller: 'NewsController'
            }).
            when('/players', {
                templateUrl: 'views/players.php',
                controller: 'PlayersController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
}]);

lax.controller('NewsController', function($scope) {
$scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
});


lax.controller('PlayersController', function($scope) {
$scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From angular 1.2.0, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. You have to load it separately and declare the dependency.

Update your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
```

And Js:

```
var lax = angular.module('lax', ['ngRoute']);
```

For more information: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Answer (score 1):

Angular routes require the `route` module to be included as well.  [Here is the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) that covers this.

So, I think you may be missing the:

```
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
```

In the `<head>` of the page.

*Note: this module used to be part of Angular, but was moved out recently (1.2?).  So, some tutorials are still assuming that `$route` is built-in.

Comment: Don't forget the closing `</script>` tag! Caught me out recently.

Answer (score -1):

Adding this would work :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
```

but it will not work without internet access when running for a first time ,Therefore you should ng-route dependency to your project and refer that in your html file

[How to add ng-route dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-route)

Comment: Please either provide a solution with codes inserted into post, or just comment below the question. Thx.