# How to use "data-ng-view" in AngularJS [Best Practice]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="BookApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css"/>
    <title>My Book</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>// I suspect this line is wrong
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my app.js

```
var NoteApp = angular.module("BookApp", ["ngResource"]).
config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: 'book.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

var ListCtrl = function($scope, $location) {
$scope.book = "test pass";
};
```

Here is my book.html

```
<h1>Hello: {{book}}</h1>
```

When U run the application nothing is displayed. How can debug this? what may be wrong?
I even trued ng-view, but VS Studio says "Attribute must be followed by = sign" ... but what i have to assign by using = sign?

Here is exception

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module BookApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

I made following changes by adding ngRoute

```
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", ["ngResource","ngRoute"])
```

Issue resolved, but what is the best practice?

Comment: from angular 1.2.0, ngRoute has been moved to its own module. What version of angular are you using?

Comment: take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974214/angularjs-ng-view-not-working/20974273#20974273

Comment: Does Visual Studio support AngularJS?

Comment: @jeff_kile: Visual Studio is just an editor, not an environment to run code.

Comment: Issue resolved, but what is the best practice?

Comment: Read http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: regarding the comment about Visual Studio. what was answer is correct but maybe you were asking if you can integrate a visual studio project with angularjs. If that was the route that you were going then I suggest looking this visual studio template: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeangular-template and/or read my investigation here: http://blog.beolle.com/2014/05/aspnet-mvc4-with-javascript-framework.html

Comment: @jeff_kile: Visual Studio is absolutely an environment to run code.  I recommend Dan Walin's excellent introduction, AngularJS Fundamentals In 60-ish Minutes, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM in which Dan uses Visual Studio as both an editor and an environment to run code to teach the fundamentals of AngularJS.