# $injector:modulerr error caused by routeProvider implementation

Tags: angularjs

Try to implement route in angularjs, it shows Error: $injector:modulerr?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
// the code below caused error
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/action/:index', {
        templateUrl: 'edit.html'
    });
});
```

I can't see what's wrong here.

Comment: you need to define `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);` For more information, check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974214/angularjs-ng-view-not-working/20974273#20974273

Comment: @KhanhTO tried but didn't work too.

Comment: did you check the link?

Comment: @KhanhTO I did. I included the js too. I found a strange thing. My url don't have the # symbol.

Comment: that is another problem. If you use `<a>` tag to navigate, just add the # to the href. Something like `href="#/action/1"`

Comment: @KhanhTO I mean the default should have /#/ in the end, but mine don't have.

Comment: what does the error say next?